# how can I convert the date in this array to date type object in Ruby

Tags: ruby, date

I have the following array:

```
open_emails = [["2012-04-21", 5], ["2012-04-20", 1], ["2012-04-22", 4]];
```

But I want it to be in the format:

```
open_emails = [[4545446464, 5], [35353535, 1], [353535353535, 4]];
```

ie. the dates in milliseconds

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `to_time` and the `to_i` methods

```
require 'date' # not required if you're using rails
open_emails = [["2012-04-21", 5], ["2012-04-20", 1], ["2012-04-22", 4]]
open_emails.map { |s, i| [Date.parse(s).to_time.to_i, i] }
# => [[1334959200, 5], [1334872800, 1], [1335045600, 4]]
```

In Ruby 1.8 there is no `to_time`methods, instead you can use `Time.mktime`:

```
open_emails.map { |s, i| [Time.mktime(*s.split('-')).to_i, i] }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have `#to_time` method (older Ruby), you can either convert it manually (using `Time#local`), or do something like this instead:

```
Date.parse(s).strftime('%s').to_i
```

Or, skip `Date` altogether, and use

```
Time.local(*s.split('-').map{|e| e.to_i}).to_i
```